# AWS VPC Deleted/Pending alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc

I'm struggling to find any information of possibility to setup an alert whenever a VPC Peering connection was deleted or a new one is a Pending acceptance. Is it possible to setup such an alert? How/where I should look to? AWS documentation is nightmare to me and finding anything is even worse.

Answer (score 0):

That is totally possible using AWS Config with SNS.

[Read more about AWS Config here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/resource-config-reference.html)

[A tutorial on how to Implement AWS Config with SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/config-email-resource-deleted/)

Comment: So If I setup a rule in cloudwatch like this. Do I have to setup something in Config also?

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.config"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Config Configuration Item Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "messageType": [
      "ConfigurationItemChangeNotification"
    ],
    "configurationItem": {
      "resourceType": [
        "AWS::EC2::VPC"
      ],
      "resourceId": [
        "ResourceDiscovered",
        "ResourceDeleted"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```